# joint and conditional probability ( 2 variables )

Tags: probability

Given a table of conditional probability, how can i find the probability of y = 1 ?

y|x             x = 0         x = 1

y=0            1 - a           0

y=1              0                   1-a

y=2             a                    a

I am new in probability, the question might be really easy but i would appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the two possible values for $x$ are $0$ and $1$,

$P(Y=1) = P(Y=1|X=0)\cdot P(X=0)+P(Y=1|X=1)\cdot P(X=1)$

We are given that $P(Y=1|X=0)=0$ and $P(Y=1|X=1)=1-a$

Therefore, $P(Y=1) =(1-a)\cdot P(X=1)$

Since we are not given $P(X=1)$, this is the most that we can simplify.